# What is the most elegant way to extract 2 values from a spark dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a scala method that reads a dataframe that will always consist of 2 int values in a single column (epochs)

```
value
---------
134535345
324531245
```

What is the most elegant way to extract these values into 2 int `vals` in Scala?

Comment: val Array(first, second) = df.map(_.getInt(0)).collect()

Comment: @User9123 thanks! Put this as an answer so I can vote and mark it as chosen answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **val Array(...)**:

```
val Array(first, second) = df.map(_.getInt(0)).collect()
```